# Select root element in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, stenciljs

How would you go about targeting the root/host element of a component in React?

I want to avoid using `document.querySelector(ELEMENT)` which would grab the first element in the dom.

For example,
in Stencil.JS you can select the root element just be declaring a root element as such:

`@Element root: HTMLElement` 
`this.root.querySelector("...")`

Comment: You are looking for `refs`. https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useRef#manipulating-the-dom-with-a-ref. You would assign a ref to the topmost dom node in your react component and then use this ref to access the actual HTML element and do what you need.

Comment: *root/host element of a component in React* - do you mean the parent element of the component or a root of the application?